# Can't customize color palette types on Material UI theme in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I create a type interface to add custom properties to the Palette like so:

```
declare module @material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme {
  interface PaletteColor {
    transparent?: string;
    gradient?: PaletteColor;
  }
  interface Palette {
    gradient?: PaletteColor;
    transparent?: PaletteColor;
    secondary?: {
      transparent?: string;
    }
  }

  interface PaletteColorOptions {
    main?:string;
    dark?:string;
    light?:string;
    transparent?: string;
    gradient?: string;
    test?: string
  }
}
```

I am trying to a lot of interfaces to get it to work...

Then I use those types in my theme like this:

```
export default function createMyTheme(options: ThemeOptions) {
    return createMuiTheme({
      ...options,
    })
  }
```

I use that function to create my main theme by importing it and calling it:

```
const theme = createMyTheme({});
```

And then I set my component style like this:
background: theme.palette.gradient.main,

and it tells me this:

```
Property 'gradient' does not exist on type 'Palette'.
```

Environment:
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.2",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"typescript": "^3.7.5"

Here is my full theme:

```
const theme = createMyTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#5FB9A6',
      dark: 'linear-gradient(-68deg, #151E27 , #335850)',
      gradient: 'linear-gradient(-68deg, #151E27 , #335850)'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#C68A77',
      transparent: 'rgba(198, 138, 119, 0.7)'
    },
    error: {
      light: '#e5a0a0',
      main: '#CD5C5C',
      dark: '#992c2c',
    },
    text: {
      primary:'#20383C',
      secondary: '#151E27',
      hint: 'rgba(32, 56, 60, 0.7)'
    },
    background: {
      paper: '#fff'
    },
    common: {
      white: "#FFF"
    }
  },
  typography: {
     fontFamily: '"Work Sans"'
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue :((

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the documentation you need `module augmentation` to add custom properties to the palette.

What I did was:

Created a file `expanded-theme.ts` in the root directory (same directory where `App.tsx` is)

```
import '@material-ui/core/styles';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette {
    myCustomColor?: Palette['primary'];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    myCustomColor?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}
```

Next, you can define the custom properties in your theme (I did not need to import `expanded-theme.ts`)

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';

// ...

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    myCustomColor: {
      main: 'blue'
    }
  }
});

// ...

<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>

//...
```

Now you can use `myCustomColor` in your styles :).

Comment: This will not allow to add gradiet to the primary color or does it? Thats the tricky part. Adding a color is easy with ts here, but adding a option inside a color like: primary.gradient is not easy. Do. you have a solution for this as well?

Answer (score 7):

This seem to work for me with MUI v5, added extra custom color "tertiary"

```
import {
  createTheme,
  responsiveFontSizes,
} from "@mui/material/styles";

    
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: true;
    sm: true;
    md: true;
    lg: true;
    xl: true;
    mobile: true;
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
  interface Palette {
    tertiary: Palette["primary"];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    tertiary?: PaletteOptions["primary"];
  }
  interface PaletteColor {
    lighter?: string;
    darker?: string;
  }
  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    lighter?: string;
    darker?: string;
  }
}

let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      lighter: "#F2D383",
      light: "#6E5B54",
      main: "#60504a",
      dark: "#614941",
      darker: "#473630",
    },
    secondary: {
      lighter: "#F5F5F5",
      light: "#f7f7f7",
      main: "#e7e7e7",
      dark: "#787878",
      darker: "#2e2e2e",
    },
    tertiary: {
      main: "#ff0000",
      contrastText: "#787878",
    },
    background: {
      default: "#e7e7e7",
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#5F5049",
    },
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1200,
      xl: 1536,
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 640,
      laptop: 1200,
      desktop: 1600,
    },
  },
});

theme = createTheme(theme, {
  components: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.tertiary,main,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 2):

For if I want a new custom color palette `neutral` , then this worked for me, :

Inside `mui.d.ts` in root of project

```js
import "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";
declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface PaletteOptions {
    neutral: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
}
```

And put it in the include of `tsconfig.json`

```
...
"include": [... , mui.d.ts]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get this to work as well, and I'm missing something very fundamental. Where does code for `declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme'` actually go? I tried creating a `types.d.ts` file, and then in my entry `index.js` file, I include it it like this:
`import './config/types.d';`

...but I still get the same sort of type error you're getting. As for your above example, it looks like MUI's example has quotes around `'@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme'`, but your code does not. Also, their example shows actually importing the modules from MUI that are then modified. And finally, your code looks self-referential (e.g. the gradient definition in interface PaletteColor is also PaletteColor). I don't know if any of those things are actually problematic, though.

My `types.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { Palette } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
//https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Palette {
    background: {
      appSubHead: string;
    };
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    background?: {
      appSubHead?: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I just declared the module in my src/theme/index.ts file (with the same syntax you've used in your example), above the code where I use createMuiTheme({ ...// }) to customize the Material UI theme, and it satisfies the conditions without TypeScript complaining.

Comment: I'd like to stress the importance of the import statement being outside the "declare module" declaration. Importing within the "declare module" (which a good chunk of answers use) did not work for me...

Answer (score -1):

My Approach in MUI5. In real case production apps we define seperate files for palettets and components etc. Inside the palatte.ts file I have done the Module Augmentation.
My theme.ts File

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import palatte from './theme/palette';

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: palatte,
  typography: {
    fontFamily: roboto.style.fontFamily,
  },
});

export default theme;
```

My palette.ts file

```
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    primaryLight: Palette['primary'];
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    primaryLight: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}

export const palatte = {
  primary: {
    main: '#556cd6',
  },
  secondary: {
    main: '#19857b',
  },
  error: {
    main: red.A400,
  },
  primaryLight: {
    main: 'yellow',
    contrastText: '#616161',
  },
};
export default palatte;
```

**Module Augmentation**

Module augmentation is achieved by creating a new TypeScript module that re-declares the interface of the original Material-UI module, and adding new properties or methods to it. These new properties or methods can then be used to extend the behavior of the original component.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using material-ui with create-react-app and typescript. Importing Palette worked for me.

```
import { Palette } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette'
```

Comment: import { Palette } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette'

Comment: It's better to edit your answer rather than adding it as a comment. However, this might not be available for you if you have a new account. I'll add it for you.