# Extend existing category inside MUI Theme

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to add a few properties to the existing options inside of MUI's theme palette. Below is an example:

```
declare module @material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme {
  interface CustomOptions extends SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    lightest?: string
    darkest?: string
  }


  interface InfoPalette {
    info: CustomOptions
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    info: CustomOptions
  }

  interface Palette {
    info: InfoPalette
  }
}
```

The desired outcome is to add `lightest` and `darkest` as properties to the main color categories in the theme such as `info`, `success`, etc. I can add new categories for custom styles successfully but I cannot extend existing ones. Typescript still complains these properties don't exist.

Here is another thread with essentially the same question but the answer does not actually address the situation: [Can't customize color palette types on Material UI theme in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424596/cant-customize-color-palette-types-on-material-ui-theme-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend interface, change it to:

```js
declare module @material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme {
  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    lightest?: string
    darkest?: string
  }

  interface InfoPalette {
    info: SimplePaletteColorOptions 
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    info: SimplePaletteColorOptions 
  }

  interface Palette {
    info: InfoPalette
  }
}
```